# Selecting products that haven't been made in 2 years

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the products that havn't been made in the last 2 years. I'm not that great with SQL but here's what i've started with and it doesn't work.

Lets say for this example that my schema looks like this

prod_id, date_created, num_units_created.

I'll take any advice i can get.

```
select id, (select date from table
            where date <= sysdate - 740) older,
           (select date from table
            where date >= sysdate - 740) newer 
from table 
where newer - older
```

I'm not being clear enough.

Basically i want all products that havn't been produced in the last 2 years. Whenever a product is produced, a line gets added. So if i just did sysdate <= 740, it would only give me all the products that were produced from the beginning up til 2 years ago.

I want all products that have been produced in the at least once, but not in the last 2 years.

I hope that clears it up.

Comment: Can you tell us what your schema looks like?

Comment: How does your table look like?

Comment: Umm i'm not actually sure. I know it's just off the one table so you should just be able to do it off the date in that table right?

Comment: say there's only 2 columns id and date.

Comment: Can you provide more information about what `older` and `newer` columns are for?  You can use `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -24)` to get a date two years in the past.

Comment: @Catfish: What version of Oracle are you using?

Answer (score 6):

GROUP BY with HAVING

```
select id, max(date)
from table
group by id
having max(date) < add_months(sysdate,-24)
```

Comment: This seems like it'll work. Can you explain to me how it works?

You are selecting the most recent date where the most recent date is less than 2 years ago? 

Should that be select id,max(date) from table group by id having date < add_months(sysdate, -24)??

Can you explain why that is wrong?

Comment: Because you want to know when the LATEST date is before two years ago. The max is the latest date.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use SQL's dateadd function.

```
where date < dateadd(year,-2,getdate())
```

would be a where clause that would select records with date less than 2 years from the current date.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:  If you want to go by days, use dateadd(d,-740,getdate())

Comment: DATEADD doesn't exist in Oracle, `ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -24)` is equivalent.

Comment: Fair enough.  I saw the SQL tag in the question.  Thanks.

Comment: That's one little behavior I detested about IBM in the day and detest about Microsoft when it happens:  co-opting common words and phrases to designate specific products.  There's the IBM Personal Computer, Microsoft SQL Server, two different varieties of Disk Operating System (hint:  the one I was originally familiar with ran on 360s), and more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
select id, date
from table
where date <= (sysdate - 730);
```

Comment: Guess this would return ids that have been produced more than 2 years ago, but not remove those that have not been produced within the last two years.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE date + (365*2) <= sysdate;
```

Use `SELECT id, date, other, columns ...` if you need to get them at the same time.

Comment: Guess this would return ids that have been produced more than 2 years ago, but not remove those that have not been produced within the last two years. Also be careful with leap years.